# Consumer configurations - when does the consumer commit offset when we set enable.auto.commit to true

Tags: apache-kafka

I've set enable.auto.commit to true and auto.commit.interval.ms to 10,000 (i.e., 10 sec). Now my question is - If the consumer gets 100 records when it first polled and the listener is processing one-by-one record and it processed only 80 records in 10 sec, does it commit and advance the offset by 80 or 100?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The offset being committed would be the amount that was polled, not the amount that was processed.

You'll want to disable auto-commits and do it yourself if you want to gaurantee that all records in a poll have been processed